# Finding an equivalent of $ u_{n}=\prod_{k=1}^{n} k^k $

Tags: sequences-and-series, asymptotics

I would like to find an equivalent of:

$$ u_{n}=\prod_{k=1}^{n} k^k $$

I managed to find and asymptotic expansion of $ \ln(u_{n}) $ whose precision is $ o(n) $:

$$ \ln(u_{n})=\frac{1}{2}n^2\ln(n)-\frac{n^2}{4}+\frac{1}{2}n\ln(n)+o(n)$$

Indeed: $$ \ln(u_{n}) \sim \frac{1}{2}n^2\ln(n)$$

Introducing: $ v_{n}=\ln(u_{n})-\frac{1}{2}n^2\ln(n)$, we have:

$$ v_{n}-v_{n-1} \sim -\frac{n}{2}$$

So: $$ v_{n} \sim \sum_{k=2}^nv_{k}-v_{k-1} \sim -\frac{n^2}{4}$$

Introducing $$ w_{n}=v_{n}+\frac{n^2}{4}$$ I get:

...
$$ w_{n} \sim  \sum_{k=2}^nw_{k}-w_{k-1} \sim\frac{1}{2}n\ln(n)$$

And $$x_{n}=w_{n}-\frac{1}{2}n\ln(n) \Longrightarrow x_{n}-x_{n-1}=o(1)\Longrightarrow x_{n}=o(n)$$

As $$ x_{n}=0+o(n) $$ the method used for $v_{n}$ and $w_{n}$ becomes useless, so how can I determine that $o(n)$?

Comment: $u_n$ is known as [hyperfactorial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial#Hyperfactorial) (see also, at [MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Hyperfactorial.html))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we wanted to we could rewrite it as

$$\begin{array}{c l} 1^1\cdot 2^2\cdot 3^3\cdots n^n & =(1\cdot2\cdots n)\times (2\cdot3\cdots n)\times\cdots \big((n-1)\cdot n\big) \times n \\
& = \frac{n!}{0!}\times \frac{n!}{1!}\times \cdots \times \frac{n!}{(n-1)!} \\
& = \frac{n!^{\,n}}{G(n+1)} \end{array}$$

where $G(\cdot)$ is the [Barnes G function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BarnesG-Function.html).

Anyway, with the [Euler-Maclaurin formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula) we have

$$\begin{array}{c l} \log u_n & = \sum_{k=1}^n k\log k \\
& = \color{Blue}{\int_1^n x\log xdx}+\color{DarkBlue}{\frac{1\log 1+n\log n}{2}}+\color{Purple}{\frac{-1/2}{2!}\big( (1+\log n)-(1+\log 1)\big)}+\color{Maroon}\cdots \\
& = \color{Blue}{\frac{n^2}{2}\left(\log n-\frac{1}{2}\right)+\frac{1}{4}}+\color{DarkBlue}{\frac{n\log n}{2}}-\color{Purple}{\frac{\log n}{4}}+\color{Maroon}\cdots \end{array}$$